# "local staff" in a shopping mall

Tags: expressions

Someone used this in a sentence:

> *local staff* in a shopping mall

to highlight the employees of that shopping mall are locals. I admit that I've never heard expressions such as "local staff", is that a proper English? I heard "local communities", "security staff", but "local staff"?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with most adjective-noun combinations, including *"local staff"*.

Comment: Yes, It's even a somewhat common phrase.